# Reading a customised heating schedule file in C#

Tags: c#

I have written a an algorithm file in C# that is going to control an experimental heating system. In order for it work it uses a schedule that looks similar to below kept in a text file (minus bullet points & headers which are not part of the file).

### Time | Action

- 00:00 - SP
- 00:15 - SP
- 00:30 - SP
- 06:00 - SP
- 07:00 - CT
- 13:15 - MT

I have got a file stream to read the file line by line. As shown below:

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(WsLoc);
file.Close();
```

What would be the easiest way to separate the time compare with the system time and then add the action on the right to a variable to be used in a if statement later? Something similar shown below is what I aim to achieve.

```
Where StreamData = System Time
DtaAction = (from file)

If DtaAction = SP

Else if DtaAction = MT
```

Comment: _"experimental heating system"_ - a fire?

Comment: Well fire does make a small part of it.... Referring to a typical heating system installation you would find in a commercial building or home.... Boiler, pipes radiators etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string.Split and StreamRead.ReadLine to get your data. You'll also probably want to use a time span tolerance if you're trying to compare the time from the file against system time (so that it doesn't have to match down to 1/10000000 of a second, which is unlikely to ever get a match):

```
var stream = new FileStream("myfile.txt", FileMode.Open);
var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
   // read in the current line of the file
   var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
        continue;

   // split the line by the hyphen, trim the whitespace
   var split = line.Split(new[] { '-' }).Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();

   // parse the time, use the current date for the day
   var time = DateTime.Parse(split[0]);

   // save your action for later
   var action = split[1];

   // compare the time in the file with the current time, use a 1 second tolerance
   if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(time).Duration() < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
   {
        // if the current time is within 1 second of the time in the file
        switch(action)
        {
             case "SP":
                break;
             default:
                break;
        }
   }
}
```

As a side note, if you have control over the file type, this data seems like it might fit better as XML. C# has an extensive library of LINQ-to-XML functions that make parsing XML significantly easier than parsing text files.

Comment: Do you mean HH:mm (hour:minute)? If so, I believe the Parse method should work with that format by default (assuming your Thread.CurrentCulture is en-US or any other culture which uses similar DateTime formats). If you're getting parsing errors, you can use DateTime.ParseExact which lets you specify the format of the string being parsed.

Comment: Oh ok, i was wondering because when i try to write a line to the screen to specify the action taking place. it writes it for the whole schedule not for the specific time.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your 'if' statement where you compare the parsed time against system time. If you update your question with the code you're using and a description of what's happening, we might be able to help out further.

Comment: I found the bug in my submission. We need to use the Duration() method to take the equivalent of an absolute value of the TimeSpan. I've updated my submission

Comment: Other than a silly mistake on my own part with an empty schedule file. It works brilliantly. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Split()` to split the contents of the line into the various components. Use a `switch` statement to execute code based on the variable ... something like this:

```
string[] parts = line.Split('-');
if(parts.Length != 2)
    throw new NotSupportedException();
string time = parts[0].Trim();
var currentTime = DateTime.Now();
string action = parts[1].Trim();
switch(action)
{
    case "SP":
        DoSPAction();
        break;
    case "CT":
        DoCTAction();
        break;
    case "MT":
        DoMTAction();
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("unsupported action");
}
```